# C++ different variable initalization

Tags: c++

so what are the major differences between `int a = 10;` and `int a(10);` ? Are there some performances variations, or anything like this ?

Comment: There is some difference for classes, but for a plain `int` there is none.

Comment: What are these differences ?

Comment: [Documentation on the many different types of initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is dupe for this, but I can't find any right now, so here is an answer:

---

> so what are the major differences between int `a = 10;` and `int a(10);` ?

The first is copy-initialization, the second is direct initialization. They both result in an int with the value 10.

> Are there some performances variations, or anything like this ?

For primitives like `int`: no. For classes/structs there might be. Copy-initialization will call the copy-constructor of a class, that might do some work. For example the copy-constructor of `std::vector` will copy each element of the vector which can become costly

```
std::vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = a;

std::cout << a.size() << "/" << b.size(); // will print 3/3
```

In some cases copy-elision takes place, so that

```
std::vector<int> c = std::vector<int>();
```

will *not* invoke the copy-constructor.

For (much) more information about initialization see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).